# Object won't retain position or animation when exported

Tags: animation, objects, export, import, .fbx

I am trying to export this plane in the center of the room. I can't get it to export with it's position in tact. Also I have it animated to disappear from the render at frame 30. This won't stick to the export either. I am also trying to export the object of all of the pieces of the frame when it shatters. This animation doesn't get exported either. Also all of the pieces of the plane appear scattered all around the new scene with no animation or position applied at all.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is how these objects import into a new blender file with a similar room.
[image]

Here is the file. How do I export the plane and the broken pieces of the plane after it shatters and import them into a new file?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10G93zGssfynaHU4Ed2_Rip69pIfNeGin/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. First I open up the file that does NOT contain the object that I want to import. Then I go to File > Append. In the dialog that comes up, I navigate to the .blend file that contains the object that I want to import. I open this .blend file in the dialog box and it actually opens like a folder. Inside it are many directories including a folder called "Object." I open the Object folder and all the objects in the blender file exist in this directory as stand alone files so I just click the one I want to import.

The object now appears in my current blender file. The thing that's amazing is that the object seems to retain all of its properties like position and animations.